# Overloading functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, overloading

I want to right a code in MATLAB which calculates a given formula, and I want to write the code with the same notation as in the given formula. In the formula I have two different functions with the same name but that only differ in the number of the arguments: `Kn(a,b)` and `Kn(a)`.

Is there a way in MATLAB to define overloading functions like in c++?

Comment: Yes, call the function by the same name and put it at a higher position in your path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to define two functions of the same name with a different number of input arguments, you should define them in the same function file and use `varargin/nargin` to treat the two cases:

```
function out=Kn(varargin)

if nargin==1
  a=varargin{1};
  %
  %here do what Kn(a) does
  %
  %out=...
elseif nargin==2
  a=varargin{1};
  b=varargin{2};
  %
  %here do what Kn(a,b) does
  %
  %out=...
else
  error('Kn accepts up to 2 input arguments!')
end

%or maybe here do what both Kn(a) and Kn(a,b) do after some initial differences
%and return 'out' here
```

If the two cases are similar then this is not confusing, nor cumbersome; and if the two functions are very different than you should seriously consider using separate functions with separate names. While in paper-based scientific computations you can easily distinguish between quantities based on the number of indices, this can be **very** confusing in programming (and I would advise against it even if it was possible to do in matlab).